# How to let user quit the process of specific command in bash

Tags: bash

I have a **bash** script where I execute an *optional* command that could take a really long time, depending user input. I want to give the user the option to end the command and move on to the next process in the bash script.

here is my code currently: (with command named foocommand)

```
read -p "are you sure? [y/N]" -n 1 -r
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
    foocommand &
    pid=$!
    trap "kill $pid 2> /dev/null" EXIT
    while kill -0 $pid 2> /dev/null; do
      for s in / - \\ \|; do
        printf "\r$s";sleep .1
      done
    done
    trap - EXIT
fi
```

The above code has a spinner to tell the user that the command is working. I would like to allow the user to be able to input "q" when the spinner is spinning to quit the command "foocommand" from finishing, execute some cleanup code, and move on.

I think this is possible to put all the above code into a while command and break if the user ever inputs a character and have an if statement to execute some cleanup. But that's just one possible solution.

Comment: I would look at backgrounding the spinner like you did `foocommand` and save its PID as well. You would then retain control to take additional input to catch the `'q'`. You could then `kill` the PID for the spinner and `foocommand` and run your cleanup code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for?  Setting TMOUT makes read time out after the number of seconds, so if the user enters "q" then hits Enter, the next TMOUT...read should get it.

```
read -p "are you sure? [y/N]" -n 1 -r
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
    sleep 60 &
    pid=$!
    trap "kill $pid 2> /dev/null" EXIT
    while kill -0 $pid 2> /dev/null; do
      for s in / - \\ \|; do
        printf "\r$s";sleep .1
      done
      TMOUT=0 read ans || continue
      [[ $ans == q ]] && exit
    done
    trap - EXIT
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for giving an answer, and this does in fact allow me to press q and enter to exit the command, but it stops the spinner

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused as to what you want then.  You said to quit the command "foocommand", which would cause the spinner to stop anyway, no?